# Python: Save png subplots with titles etc

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to save my subplots as I created them like this:

However, in the actual image, it does not show the titles or axis numbers etc. just the plots on a black background

As requested I post the code here to see if there is a problem with the code:

```
indexes = pai_sum.index.tolist()
num_rows = 5
num_cols = 4
num_plots = len(indexes)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(num_rows, num_cols, figsize=(12, 15))
axs = axs.flatten()
for i, index in enumerate(indexes):
    # Break the loop if all indexes have been plotted
    if i == num_rows * num_cols:
        break
    


ax = axs[i]

# Extract the values for the current index
values = pai_sum.loc[index].values
columns = [f'{col}' for col in pai_sum.columns]

bars = ax.bar(columns, values, color='lightgreen')

# Set the title for the subplot with a number
if i < 4:
    ax.set_title(f'{i+1}. {index}')
elif i == 5:
    title_parts = index.split('-')
    main_title = title_parts[0].strip()
    additional_info = title_parts[1].split('(')[1].strip(')')
    ax.set_title(f'{i+1}. {main_title} {additional_info}')
elif i == 6:
    title_parts = index.split('-')
    main_title = title_parts[0].strip()
    additional_info = title_parts[1].split('(')[1].strip(')')
    ax.set_title(f'{i+1}. {main_title} {additional_info}')
else:
    truncated_title = index.split('-')[0].strip()
    ax.set_title(f'{i+1}. {truncated_title}')

# Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)

# Add the values inside the bars, rounding without decimals for the first 4 plots and plot 9
if i < 4 or i == 12:
    for j, value in enumerate(values):
        ax.text(j, value, str(int(value)), ha='center', va='bottom')
else:
    for j, value in enumerate(values):
        ax.text(j, value, str(round(value, 2)), ha='center', va='bottom')

# Adjust the y-axis limits to provide more space above the bars
ax.set_ylim(top=max(values) * 1.2)

for j in range(i + 1, num_rows * num_cols):
    fig.delaxes(axs[j])

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
fig.savefig('flagged.png')
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: is this code formatted exactly like you are running it? If so, I assume you'd want everything below line ~14 `ax = axs[i]` indented

Comment: This code is not a minimal, reproducible example. `pai_sum` is undefined.

Comment: No the code is working I snipped some things out.. It just shows everything correct when running it but the export picture is not as expected

Comment: my problem is here: plt.show() -> shows everything as expected, whereas fig.savefig('flagged.png') does not save as expected

Comment: This code does not have enough information to run, so I cannot test it to reproduce the error.

Comment: The example isn't reproducible

Comment: Why not use `plt.savefig('flagged.png')` instead?

Comment: The code is incorrectly indented; that makes it hard(er) to find an error. Unless you do mean to have `i = num_rows * num_cols`, but then you don't need the for loop.